# Getting Permission denied when trying to import .sql file with \i

Tags: postgresql

I have connected to my Postgres database and I want to run some seed files. When I run `\i /home/arch/dev/project/src/db/schema/create.sql` I get `Permission Denied`

Is there a way I can make it so the postgres user on my os has permission to run files owned by other users or perhaps make it so I can run `psql` from my linux user account rather than having to switch to the postgres user?

Comment: `psql` can be run from any account. The `-U`  part is what database user it connects as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can make it so the postgres user on my os has permission to run files owned by other users

The only permission needed is to read the file, and traverse the directory tree to get to the file. These can be set with `chmod`

> make it so I can run psql from my linux user account rather than having to switch to the postgres user?

There are many options.  If your current pg_hba local setting is just `local all all peer`, then add a new database superuser which is named the same as your linux account name.  Or Change pg_hba.conf so you are using `md5` (or `trust`, or `scram-sha-256`, or something fancier), rather than `peer`.  Or keep using `peer`, but provide a user map and edit pg_ident.conf to allow your linux user to connect.